# How to add grammar library to voice to text file so I can used voice to text

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create voice to text recognize application. I have checked many examples that only work with pre-added text into this application. How can I add all grammar libraries to this application so that when I speak anything that time I get it converted into text.

My example code:

```
 Choices commands = new Choices();
 commands.Add(new string[] { "chrome", "notepad", "microsoftword", "paint", "close", "demo" });
 GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
 gBuilder.Append(commands);
 Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);
 recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
 recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
 recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
```

Comment: You want to add every word in the language?

Answer (score 1):

OK I'm not sure what you've done so far, but I've just tried this and it works just fine for me.

Add the System.Speech reference to your project.

add this at the top

```
Using System.Speech;
Using System.Speech.Recognition;
```

For my basic application, I just added a `RichTextBox1` to the form to try out the basic functionality. Then I added this code to the program :-

```
 SpeechRecognizer sRecognize = new SpeechRecognizer();
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
 }

 void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
 {
     richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Result.Text.ToString() + " ");
 }
```

You might need to set up the voice recognition, but that is straightforward.